# Easy paisa Payment Gateway Integration Errors

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I need help as working on EasyPaisa Payment Gateway Integration getting the error.

We have a store on EasyPaisa and received payment integration guideline how to integrate.

They have mentioned that by posting the following form  https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf

```
<form action="https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf" method="POST" target="_blank">
<! -- Store Id Provided by Easypay-->
<input name="storeId" value="43" hidden = "true"/>
<! -- Amount of Transaction from merchant’s website -->
<input name="amount" value="10" hidden = "true"/>
<! – Post back URL from merchant’s website -- >
<input name="postBackURL" value=" http://www.my.online-store.com/transaction/MessageHandler" hidden = "true"/>
<! – Order Reference Number from merchant’s website -- >
<input name="orderRefNum" value="1101" hidden = "true"/>
<! – Expiry Date from merchant’s website (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”expiryDate” value=”20140606 201521”>
<! – Merchant Hash Value (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”merchantHashedReq” value=”askldjflaksdjflkasdf======asdfas dfkjaskdf”>
<! – If Merchant wants to redirect to Merchant website after payment completion (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”autoRedirect” value=”0”>
<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”paymentMethod” value=”0”>
<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”emailAddr” value=”test.abcd@abcd.com”>
<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >
<input type =”hidden” name=”mobileNum” value=”03325241789”>
<! – This is the button of the form which submits the form -- >
<input type = “image” src=”checkout-button-with-logo.png border=”0” name= “pay”>
</form>
```

When I submit this form with our storeId get the following error on easypaisa website

[Easy Paisa Description about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z6Yp.png)

any help IS I am missing some things

Comment: can we integrate easy paisa in php or its framework laravel?

Comment: If your problem hasn't been solved yet please do let me know I will give you the complete working code.

Comment: @shaz3e your code works on PHP?

Comment: @Zain Ali yes my code is working and I am using it with WHMCS

Answer (score 3):

Your form input is wrong that is why it is not working.

You just change this and check it will work.

```html
<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >

Replace this:

<input type =”hidden” name=”paymentMethod” value=”0”>

<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >

By one of the following.

1. For Mobile Account:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="MA_PAYMENT_METHOD">


2. For Retailer/Shop Account:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="OTC_PAYMENT_METHOD/">


3. For Credit/Debit Card:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="CC_PAYMENT_METHOD">
```

I have the same issue but when I tried this its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a problem in the code snippet given by Easypaisa's documentation.

The inverted commas (double-quotes) are wrong

Replace ” with "

These are :

```
<input type =”hidden” name=”paymentMethod” value=”0”>
```

Should be :

```
<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >

Replace this:

<input type =”hidden” name=”paymentMethod” value=”0”>

<! – If merchant wants to post specific Payment Method (Optional) -- >

By one of the following.

1. For Mobile Account:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="MA_PAYMENT_METHOD">


2. For Retailer/Shop Account:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="OTC_PAYMENT_METHOD/">


3. For Credit/Debit Card:

<input type ="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="CC_PAYMENT_METHOD">
```